# Курс на python, вещественные числа. Задача вычисления площади треугольника. Runtime error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пробую решение, которое здесь уже описано, - не помогает.
Детальнее ошибки нет, потому что проверяет робот, и я не вижу, что он вводит.
Вот код:

```
# Даны длины сторон треугольника. Вычислите площадь треугольника
# площадь по формуле Герона
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
p = (a + b + c) / 2  # полупериметр
s = (p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))
if s < 0:
    s *= -1
print('{:.6f}'.format(pow(s, 0.5)))
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка

Comment: А у вас, значит, локально все работает?

Comment: поменяйте `/ 2` -> `/ 2.` иначе это будет "правильно" работать только в Python 3

Comment: @MaxU, указан ведь 3-й Питон. Ну, хотя проверяющая система может думать иначе

Comment: @КириллМалышев, возможно робот работает под Python 2

Comment: Я вот что думаю. Может, у вас через пробел задаются стороны по заданию?

Comment: попробовал с точкой - не принимает с тем же результатом

Comment: валится на тесте №7, поэтому ввод данных точно по очереди

Comment: а что робот говорит по поводу теста №7 - известны входные данные и ошибка?

Comment: входные данные не показывает
Test 7
Runtime error

Comment: @slemik, точно только целые числа на входе? Замените int(input()) на float(input()). Это не должно навредить в любом случае.

Comment: @КириллМалышев Помогло!!! Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если считывать вводимые числа таким образом

```
a = int(input())
```

они будут преобразовываться к типу `int`. Ведь метод `input()` возвращает строку, а `int()` пытается сделать из неё целое число. Соответственно, если ввести число с точкой, произойдёт ошибка. Чтобы считывать вещественные числа, нужно пользоваться функцией `float()`:

```
a = float(input())
```