# Найти площадь треугольника по формуле Герона

Tags: python

Заданы координаты вершин треугольника. Найти его площадь по формуле Герона.
Написала вроде бы программку, но не идет. Не понимаю где ошиблась?

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3=list(map(int,input().split()))
a=math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)
b=math.sqrt((x3-x1)**2+(y3-y1)**2)
c=math.sqrt((x2-x3)**2+(y2-y3)**2)
p=(a+b+c)/2
resultat=math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))
prit(resultat)
```

Comment: Ну и чего с этим делать?

Comment: Найти в задаче ошибки

Comment: Для этого есть отладчик?

Comment: Я только учу питон. Как им пользоваться?

Comment: Выполнять программу по шагам и смотреть, в каком месте что-то не сходится с ожидаемым.

Comment: Во первых добавили ли вы нужные "библиотеки"? Во вторых не `prit(resultat)`  а `print(resultat)`. В третьих покажите лог ошибок.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: "но не идет" - напишите детально, что вы делаете, что происходит, и что такое "не идет". Вопросы без детального описания ошибки - бесполезны.

Comment: связанные вопросы [Курс на python, вещественные числа. Задача вычисления площади треугольника. Runtime error](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780696/23044), [Runtime error при вычислении площади треугольника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728789/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Вы ошиблись, преобразовывая входные данные в int. В первой строке

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

`int` необходимо заменить на `float`.

Из рекомендаций: Питон умеет возводить числа в дробные степени, поэтому вместо `math.sqrt(x)` можно использовать `x**.5`.